# Why getting message unfortunately has stopped when adding button click event?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Without the button code it's working fine.
I didn't see anything in the LogCat.

This is the MainActivity.java code:

```
package com.test.webservertest;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.AndroidRuntimeException;
import android.util.Xml;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.util.EncodingUtils;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    private static final int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;
    public static MainActivity currentActivity;
    TextToSpeech mTts;
    private String targetURL;
    private String urlParameters;
    private Button btnClick;
    private String clicking = "clicked";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setContentView(new SingleTouchEventView(this, null));

        addListenerOnButton();

        currentActivity = this;

        initTTS();


    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        btnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkipbutton);

        btnClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {

                Intent browserIntent =
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.mkyong.com"));
                startActivity(browserIntent);

            }

        });

    }
```

And in the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:text="WEBSERVER"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:id="@+id/textView"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Check Ip"
        android:id="@+id/checkipbutton"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

If i'm calling the method: addListenerOnButton(); i'm getting message on the android: unfortunately has stopped and then the program shut down.
If i'm not calling addListenerOnButton(); then the program will keep working fine.

Also when running the program if not calling the addListenerOnButton(); i don't see the button i added in the layout designer on the screen at all.

Comment: "I didn't see anything in the LogCat" -- look again. There is always a stack trace when your app crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you set the contentview twice cancelling the first with the layout of the button in it
if you comment out the second call to setContentView it may work

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 //setContentView(new SingleTouchEventView(this, null));
```

if you wish to use

SingleTouchEventView

consider adding it to your activity_main layout